# How to change a particular field value after decoding the original byte array?

Tags: java, json, avro

I have an Avro Schema which is like this -

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"new_user",
   "namespace":"com.hello",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"user_id",
         "type":[
            "long",
            "null"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"segment",
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using my above Avro Schema like this to serialize the data and which gives me a Byte Array and works fine -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Schema schema = new Parser()
            .parse("{ \"type\":\"record\", \"name\":\"new_user\", \"namespace\":\"com.hello\", \"fields\":[ { \"name\":\"user_id\", \"type\":[ \"long\", \"null\" ] }, { \"name\":\"segment\", \"type\":[ \"string\", \"null\" ] } ] }");

    byte[] originalAvrodata = getAvroBinaryData(schema);

    // how to get newAvroData byte array in which user_id 
    // is change to some other random long number?
}

private static byte[] getAvroBinaryData(Schema schema) throws IOException {
    GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    record.put("user_id", 123456L);
    record.put("segment", "hello");

    GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(os, null);

    writer.write(record, e);
    e.flush();
    byte[] byteData = os.toByteArray();
    return byteData;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I need to decode the `originalAvrodata` byte array and then change the `user_id` field value to some other `long` number and then construct a `newAvroData` byte array using the same schema which should have `user_id` field value to some random `long` number. Is this possible to do by any chance using Avro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is some commented code, which should help you get started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser()
           .parse("{ \"type\":\"record\", \"name\":\"new_user\", \"namespace\":\"com.hello\", \"fields\":[ { \"name\":\"user_id\", \"type\":[ \"long\", \"null\" ] }, { \"name\":\"segment\", \"type\":[ \"string\", \"null\" ] } ] }");

        // create example record
        GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("user_id", 123456L);
        record.put("segment", "hello");

        // serialize record
        byte[] recordData = getAvroBinaryData(schema, record);

        // de-serialize byte array to record  
        GenericRecord readRecord = readRecord(schema, recordData);

        // increment user_id field
        Long userId = (Long) readRecord.get("user_id");
        readRecord.put("user_id", userId + 1);

        // prints 123457 for the user_id
        System.out.println(readRecord);

        // serialize updated recored
        byte[] updatedRecordData = getAvroBinaryData(schema, readRecord);

        // do something with updatedRecordData
    }   

    private static GenericRecord readRecord(Schema schema, byte[] originalAvrodata) throws IOException {
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(originalAvrodata, null);       
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
        GenericRecord readRecord = null;

        try {
            readRecord = reader.read(null, decoder);            
        } catch (EOFException eofe) {
            eofe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return readRecord;
    }

    // takes the record to be serialized as an additonal parameter
    private static byte[] getAvroBinaryData(Schema schema, GenericRecord record) throws IOException {
        GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(os, null);
        writer.write(record, e);
        e.flush();
        byte[] byteData = os.toByteArray();
        return byteData;
    }
```